# handling document.visibilitychange in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to execute a service function when the window.document.visibilitychange occurs.
This event sets document.hidden and document.visibilityState.

I currently have the following working code:

```
app.factory("viewService", function($rootScope,$document) {

    var service = {

        isVisible: false,

        init: function(){

            $document[0].addEventListener("visibilitychange", service.visibilityChanged, false);

            service.visibilityChanged();
        },

        visibilityChanged: function(){

            service.isVisible = ! $document[0].hidden;
            $rootScope.$apply();
        }
    }

    return service;

});
```

I (currently, for testing purposes) show viewService.isVisible's value in a view by binding to it.

This works correctly, however it feels quite dirty and I'm sure there's a more elegant implementation.

I'm new at AngularJS and I assumed I could just do:

```
    app.factory("viewService", function(accountService, eventService, $rootScope, focus, blur, $document) {

        var service = {

            isVisible: !$document[0].hidden,

       ...
```

And isVisible would get updated since I use $document instead of document, so changing properties would get detected and applied automatically.

Where am I going wrong? What is a cleaner approach to solve this?

Comment: Well, it works but so does this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/LKbBksv7yWwMAFvUN51i?p=info
So I don't really see the added value..
Besides, it doesn't realy explain why I have to call $scope.$apply in my code.

Comment: Basically you're just re-broadcasting the event..